# How to package my own CYCLES fork as an add-on for blender (as a .zip file)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, add-on, luxrender-render-engine

I made a fork of the awesome CYCLES render engine. I wonder, can I package my fork as an add-on for blender?

I know that there are many alternative render engines for blender (e.g. LuxCoreRender). LuxCoreRender can be installed as an add-on. Can I do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not easily, the way Cycles is integrated requires access to Blender APIs that are not available to addons. In principle it is possible to do all the same things through the Python API, but that would require rewriting a lot of the Blender to Cycles conversion code.

I got this answer here https://devtalk.blender.org/t/how-to-package-my-own-cycles-fork-as-an-add-on-for-blender-as-a-zip-file/1765