# Custom Renderer as an Add-on

Tags: rendering, scripting, add-on

I have been writing a custom raytracing renderer in C++ and I would like to natively integrate it with Blender 2.8 as a custom renderer. I know that this is possible, as I have seen many projects (for example, [SORT](https://github.com/JiayinCao/SORT/)) do this. However, I am completely new to Blender plugin development and am at a loss for how to even approach writing such a plugin.

I vaguely know that I'll need to re-write all of the material nodes and that I'll need to somehow pipe data back and forth between Blender and my renderer. Other than this, I am completely lost.

The closest threads that I can find regarding this topic are [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52711/how-to-render-with-a-custom-render-engine) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115792/how-to-package-my-own-cycles-fork-as-an-add-on-for-blender-as-a-zip-file), neither of which is particularly relevant to what I'm trying to accomplish as far as I can tell.

Could someone push me in the right direction? If there is a minimal example then I could probably take it from there.

Comment: Hello world engine example in the API docs might be a good start: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.RenderEngine.html If you'd like to have custom nodes, have a look into luxcore add-on: https://github.com/LuxCoreRender/BlendLuxCore

Comment: @brockmann this I can work with, thanks!